# kernel panic message not displayed

Tags: command-line, kernel

I am manually panicking the kernel with:

```
echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

It looks like the kernel at least freezes but there are not messages from the kernel. I was expecting the kernel to panic and the panic message to be displayed on my display but this does not happen.

What am I not doing right?

Comment: Which display? Text console? Graphics console? Ssh connection?

Comment: I'm expecting something like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_panic#/media/File:Kernel-panic.jpg

Comment: That doesn't answer my question: which display are you looking at?

Comment: I only have one display and are not using an SSH connection. I'm not sure what you mean by text and graphics console but AFAIK, my display should all go black and the panic message should be displayed there instead.